# Python ElementTree script duplicating XML data when writing to CSV output

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, elementtree

I have a script which takes a folder of XML files, searches through them for a specific element and then prints the contents of the element (monitor IDs and camera IDs) out to a CSV. Simple enough, however there is a problem where the data in the CSV is duplicated.

It seems that, depending on how many items are found within the MatrixSwitch element, this is the amount of times the data is repeated in the CSV.

Say the XML only has 1 "Monitor" and 1 "Camera" , this data will be duplicated 2 times. If the next file has 3 of each, 6 in total, it will be repeated 6 times.

This is the script :

```
import csv
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenames = glob.glob("..\Lib\macros\*.xml")

for filename in filenames:

  with open(filename, 'r') as content:
    element = ET.parse(content)
    root = element.getroot()
    print(root.attrib, filename)
  e = element.findall('commands/MatrixSwitch/')
  for i in e:
    print (i.tag, i.text)


    with open('results.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:

            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([root.attrib, filename])
            for i in e:
                writer.writerow([i.tag, i.text])
```

I printed out "filenames" to see if that was somehow causing the issue, but it seems not, none of the filesnames were showing as duplicated in the list.

The expected output from each XML file, displayed in the CSV is as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm93Z.jpg

Clearly one of the loops is messed up somehow, but I'm struggling to find it .

Example XML files :

```
<macro name="NAME OF THE MACRO IS SHOWN HERE">
<execution>
<delay>0</delay>
</execution>
<parameters/>
<commands>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>1530</camera>
<monitor>1020</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>1531</camera>
<monitor>1001</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
</commands>
</macro>
```

Another one :

```
<macro name="ANOTHER NAME GOES HERE">
<execution>
<delay>0</delay>
</execution>
<parameters/>
<commands>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>201</camera>
<monitor>17</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>206</camera>
<monitor>18</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>202</camera>
<monitor>19</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>207</camera>
<monitor>20</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
</commands>
</macro>
```

Due to nested loops I now have the following, which seems to work ok :

```
import csv
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenames = glob.glob("..\Lib\macros\*.xml")

for filename in filenames:

    with open(filename, 'r') as content:
        element = ET.parse(content)
        root = element.getroot()
        print(root.attrib, filename)
        e = element.findall('commands/MatrixSwitch/')
    with open('results.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([root.attrib, filename])

        for i in e:
            print (i.tag, i.text)
            writer.writerow([i.tag, i.text])
```

Comment: You have nesting loops `for i in e:` which leads to: ***"has 3 of each, 6 in total, it will be repeated 6 times."***. Furthermore, `open/close` a file within a loop to `append` data is a antipattern.

Comment: How should I alter the loops then? Should the open of results.csv occur earlier in the script?

Comment: ***"open ... earlier in the script?"***: Yes, move it before `for filename ...` and use `open(..., 'w')` instead of `'a'`.

Comment: thanks . before I noticed you reply I had moved things around and it seems to work ...more by luck than judgement ... does what I've now done look ok?

Comment: ***"done look ok?"***: Possible solution, but it results in a invald `CSV` file format, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes . I want the name and filename on a row and then the monitors/cameras on new rows below. Works for now. Thanks very much!